# "Turn somebody in" and Turn somebody over to somebody" . Is there a difference?

Tags: idioms, synonyms

They turned him in to the police.
They turned him over to the police.
Are they exactly the same in meaning?

Comment: Though they are similar, the first gives me the impression of delivering someone to a police station, whereas with the second, the police might already be outside looking for him, chasing him, raiding his house, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/turn-sb-in?q=turn%20%20sb%20%20in), **Turn *somebody* in** means taking a criminal to the police. In my opinion, it can also mean telling the police where the criminal is, so that they can arrest them. [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/turn-in#:%7E:text=If%20you%20turn%20someone%20in,himself%20in%20to%20the%20authorities.%20%5B) agrees with me on this.

This expression is often used reflexively:

> The driver turned **himself** in two days after the accident

According to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turn%20in) (US) it can also mean to betray somebody, i.e. tell the police who committed a crime. I don't think that it has this meaning in the UK, though there is an informal expression [**dob *somebody* in**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dob-sb-in?q=dob%20%20sb%20%20in) which means to secretly tell the police that somebody has committed a crime.

To [turn somebody over to](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/turn-sb-over-to-sb) the police means "take a criminal to the police or other authority"

Answer (score 2):

I would understand *turn him over* to mean transfer physical possession, as in: *The local police turned the prisoner over to the federal marshal.*

*Turn him in* often means only to **tell** the police that he is the one they want.